# Job Application Confusion.. Help!

Tags: interviewing, resume, communication, job-search, hiring-process

I applied for a job and did not hear from the place for 2 weeks. Finally the recruitment agency (not the company itself) contacts me about the app saying "sorry, that position was filled, but we have another that we think you would be great for!". All they tell me is the TITLE of the position, they dont give me ANY details about the role - NONE. So I say yes, I would love to hear more about this other role.

Their response? They e-mail myself and the actual company saying hey! shes interested!

The company wants to set up a phone interview with me so they ask when I am available. I give them a time and at the end of the e-mail I say that I would love to hear more about the role and ask if they could send me more information about it.

I now understand that the company is under the impression that the recruitment agency has already given me the job posting.

Now I am in an awkward position because I do not want this company to think I am just grabbing at the next opportuniy, but i honestly HAVE NO IDEA what this new job entails!

The last e-mail I got was confirming our phone interview on Tuesday, and she asked "what more do you need to know about the role? If its easier, we can just discuss specifics on Tuesday".

So my question is... How do I let this woman know that I haven't actually read ANY description what so ever for this job without making myself look bad or without talking negatively about the agency...?

Please help!

Comment: Did you try asking the recruiter directly (without CC'ing the new job employer), "Could you send me the job listing/information you have on this new role?"

Answer (score 5):

Very easy, you contact her again and say "was the recruiter supposed to give me a description of the new position you want to interview me for? I haven't seen that yet... I'm certainly interested in working for (company) but I really want to know what you're looking for so I can properly prepare for the interview. Could you send me that?"

Then, after getting those details, you can decide whether to proceed or to say "now that I've got the details, I don't think this is a good fit for me because..." If not sure, do the interview and give them a chance to convince you that it sound like fun.

Nobody expects you to go in completely blind... Except the recruiter, apparently, and they should be corrected.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I'm under the impression that the woman at the actual company does not know that I originally applied for the other position. Will it reflect badly on me to mention this when I ask for the posting?

Comment: It may reflect badly on the recruiter. It shouldn't reflect badly on you. If there's a question "well, I trusted they wouldn't suggest anything I want a good fit for, so I said of course I'm interested in learning more about the opportunity... But I didn't expect them to scedule the interview before telling me more. I guess they think I'm a _really_ good fit?" Everyone has encountered recruiters who are more enthusiastic than organized; they won't be shocked and they won't blame you.

Answer (score 2):

First, just email the recruiter or if they provided a phone number in their email sig, correspondence, etc. Tell them you weren't sent a description for the job and you require this. God forbid you're phone interviewing for not just a mystery job but one that you absolutely don't want. Basically, the hierarchy of contact is you > recruiter > company, so in any case the recruiter is point of contact #1, 2 and 3. If for some reason the recruiter is virtually unreachable, absolutely let the company know you need this info too.

Just beware of closed customer service or slow response times and such on off-hours. As a side note, you can always try to find the job in the company's careers webpage, but from experience they're often unlisted positions that're being recruited.

TL;DR Just contact the recruiter and say you need a description of the job.

Comment: How do I navigate this? Do I say straight up that I originally applied for another position and she never gave me the job posting for the new one?

Comment: I'm speaking primarily from the US, but you would directly contact the person in the recruitment agency responsible for you/that position and tell them they did not provide a description of the job before setting up an interview, and you need this information.